# How can I fix a collect2: error in Cygwin?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a problem running my code in the Cygwin terminal. When I use g++ main.CPP command then I will get this collect2: error. How can I fix this problem?

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Car.h"
#include "ParkingLot.h"
#include "MyTime.h"
#include <string>

using namespace CarParking;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("FILE.TXT", std::ios::in);
    int count = 0;
    std::string line, date, vrn, inTime, outTime;
    Car car;
    ParkingLot parkingLot;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        getline(file, line);
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            int start = 0;
            date = line.substr(0, 10);
            vrn = line.substr(12, 8);
            inTime = line.substr(22, 8);
            outTime = "";
            if (line.substr(31, 1) == "-") {
                car = Car(date, vrn, MyTime(inTime));
            }
            else {
                outTime = line.substr(32, 8);
                car = Car(date, vrn, MyTime(inTime), MyTime(outTime));
            }
            parkingLot.park(car);
            if (!car.getOutTime().isBlank()) {
                parkingLot.unPark(car);
            }
        }
        char choice;
        do {
            std::cout << "\n\nWelcome to Car Parking\n\n";
            std::cout << "Menu                       Choice\n";
            std::cout << "Show Current Parked Cars    D\n";
            std::cout << "Park a car                  P\n";
            std::cout << "UnPark a car                U\n";
            std::cout << "Show History                H\n";
            std::cout << "Exit                        Q\n";
            std::cout << "Enter your choice (D/P/U/H/Q): ";
            std::cin >> choice;
            switch (choice) {
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                std::cout << "\nCars available in Parking are:" << std::endl;
                parkingLot.showCars();
                break;
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
                std::cin.ignore();
                std::cout << "\n\nEnter date (dd/mm/yy): ";
                std::cin >> date;
                std::cout << "Enter vrn: ";
                std::getline(std::cin, vrn);
                std::cout << "Enter inTime (hh:mm:ss): ";
                std::cin >> inTime;
                car = Car(date, vrn, MyTime(inTime));
                parkingLot.park(car);
                std::cout << "Car with vrn " << vrn << " has parked";
                break;
            case 'u':
            case 'U':
                std::cout << "Enter vrn: ";
                std::cin.ignore();
                std::getline(std::cin, vrn);
                std::cout << "Enter outTime (hh:mm:ss): ";
                std::cin >> outTime;
                parkingLot.unPark(vrn, MyTime(outTime));
                break;
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
                std::cout << "\nCars unparked details" << std::endl;
                parkingLot.showHistory();
                break;
            case 'Q':
                std::cout << "Program exiting...";
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "INVALID CHOICE";
                break;
            }
        } while (choice != 'Q');
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to tell us the exact text of the error message. It will be above the `collect2` part in your compiler's output

Comment: Also whatever linker error you have is related to files you don't show and also build commands you don't show. I would expect `g++ main.CPP` to be wrong as I expect you to have more than 1 cpp file.

Comment: @drescherjm Not probably; definitely.